# Python Regex Capturing Multiple Line Files based on Condition

Tags: python, regex, string, extract

I have a text file similar to below

```
<Start  
1;  
b;  
c;  
d;  
<End  
<Start  
2;  
b;  
c;  
d;  
<End  
<Start  
1;  
b;  
c;  
d;  
<End
```

Basically this text file consist of 3 sets of each starts with <Start and ends with <End.
I would like to capture only numbers with "1" only. Expected data would be as below:

```
<Start  
1;  
b;  
c;  
d;  
<End  
<Start  
1;  
b;  
c;  
d;  
<End
```

I'm trying to figure out a way on how to do this via Python Regex but couldn't find any methods up to now. Would appreciate if I can get help from this community.  Thank you in advance

Comment: Remember - you should always post your attempt, even if wrong. Open questions like this do no respect the guidelines

Answer (score 0):

You use this regex `(<Start[\s]*1;[\sa-z;]*<End)`

it will capture all strings that match the pattern between `(` and `)`

- The string starts with `<Start`
- Then could have any `*` whitespace `[\s]`
- Then there should have the string `1;`
- Then we can have whitespaces `\s`, semicolons `;` or lower cases letters `a-z`
- It finally ends with `<End`

try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/9PZPib/1)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative pattern would be ("regex_input.txt" is a file which contains exactly your input):

```
import re

# This simply loads your content
content = None
with open("regex_input.txt", "r") as f:
    content = "\n".join([line.strip() for line in f])

# The re.DOTALL option allows to capture newlines as well
pattern = re.compile("<Start[^<]*?1;.*?<End", re.DOTALL)
print(pattern.findall(content))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['<Start\n1;\nb;\nc;\nd;\n<End', '<Start\n1;\nb;\nc;\nd;\n<End']
```